# Overlap between vehicle and box collision not working ue4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

```
void ARasenmaeher::OnBeginOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    if (OtherActor->ActorHasTag("BoxCollision"))
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Overlap"));
        IsOverlapping = true;
        while (IsOverlapping == true)
        {
            AngryLevel += 10;
        }

    }
}
```

the box collision is set to overlapalldynamic, the vehicle to "Vehicle", how can i get the overlap events to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlap event doesnt fire in UE4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69965909/overlap-event-doesnt-fire-in-ue4)